# Cannot order posts by title

Tags: php, wordpress

No matter how I try or what I do, I cannot order my posts by title:

```
# Vars
global $post;

# Build
$args = array(
    'numberposts'     => -1,
    'category'        => 28,
    'orderby'         => 'title',
    'order'           => 'ASC',
    'post_type'       => 'post',
    'post_status'     => 'published' );

# Query
$tagposts = get_posts($args);

# Iterate
foreach($tagposts as $post) :

# Populate
setup_postdata($post);

# Show title, excerpt
echo '<tr><td>';
the_title();
echo '</td><td>';
the_excerpt();
echo '</td></tr>';

endforeach;
```

They always come out in the order I entered them.  I cannot even get it to order by **date**.

**EDIT: I am running 3.0.3 against MySQL on Windows**

**I should also note that the category I am searching on is a subcategory.  The results show up fine.**

**Updated with latest technique which still results in the wrong order.**

Comment: Do you have an existing post loop somewhere?

Comment: It's very possible that the theme I am using has one (PageLines).  I tried WP_Query instead and got the same result.

Comment: check out http://wordpress.org/support/topic/orderbytitle-not-working

Comment: thanks.  Was there this morning.  Nothing there helped.  this is a strange problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really weird, but I solved the problem by adding a custom filter.  Removing all of the current filters had no effect ... but this works:

```
# Vars
global $post;

# Build
$args = array(
    'numberposts'     => -1,
    'category'        => 28,
    'post_type'       => 'post',
    'post_status'     => 'published' );

# Clear
add_filter('posts_orderby', 'post_title ASC' );

# Query
$tagposts = get_posts($args);

# Iterate
foreach($tagposts as $post) :

# Populate
setup_postdata($post);

# Show title, excerpt
echo '<tr><td>';
the_title();
echo '</td><td>';
the_excerpt();
echo '</td></tr>';

endforeach;

# Order
function title_alphabetical( $orderby )
{
  return $orderby;
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I tried adding your code but it throws an error: --- Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'post_title ASC' not found or invalid function name in [...]/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 227 --- can you post the full code?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

// display posts organized by title in ascending order

```
<div class="post">

    <h1>Ordered by Post Title (Ascending)</h1>

    <?php foreach( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

        <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

</div>
```

I have not used this Codex, but it looks like it may work here as well.

```
 <?php get_posts( $args ); ?> 

    'orderby'         => 'title',
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, and it was caused by the Post Types Order plugin. If you are using a plugin like this, it may override any custom sorting in your query.